# Unable to manage tenants with WSO2 IS & Ldap

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

**WSO2 IS 5.2.0v**

Configured UserStore - primary - with ReadWriteLdapManager.
Changed the *tenant-mgmt.xml* configured the super domain(mycompany.com).
Admin user available for *mycompany.com*. Used admin as user to try manage tenant.
Looks like exception as below:

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil} -  Failed to add tenant config. tenant-domain: mytenant.com, tenant-admin: user9301.
```

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : 8
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)

**NB: ** the tenant as **ou** & under that *groups & users* as **ou** are created in Ldap.

 Is there any configuration I am configuring it in wrong way!

**Edit:**

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://192.168.1.93:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=mytenant,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
            <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=mytenant,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=mytenant,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">mytenant.com</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        </UserStoreManager>
```

**User-mgt.xml**

```
<TenantManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager">
        <Property name="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.CommonLDAPRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
        <Property name="RootPartition">dc=mytenant,dc=com</Property>
        <Property name="OrganizationalObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="OrganizationalAttribute">ou</Property>
        <Property name="OrganizationalSubContextObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="OrganizationalSubContextAttribute">ou</Property>
    </TenantManager>
```

**tenant-mgmt.xml**

Above are the changes which I made to achieve it.

Comment: Any scope on it, is there a way to rectify that. !

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your configurations.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena updated with the configurations made on Wso2IS 5.2 repository

Comment: Have you made any configuration related to a ou tenant9301.com and a user user9301?

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena, sorry that the my mistake on the edit, is here mytenant = tenant9301 itself.

Comment: What about user user9301?

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena, user belongs to the above tenant itself.